# apply sql case on select all in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get all the columns from the products table and apply sql case on pick_8 and pick_12 columns only but to do this i have to write all the column names in select. Is there any way in laravel where i can apply the simple get() method to retrieve all the columns with applying case on only 2, without having to write all the column names manually.

```
$products = Product::where('is_archive',0)->select('humanId','name','cost','retailPrice','memberPrice','points',
             DB::raw('(CASE WHEN pick_8 = 1 THEN "True" ELSE "False" END) AS pick_8'),
             DB::raw('(CASE WHEN pick_12 = 1 THEN "True" ELSE "False" END) AS pick_12'))->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve all the columns you can use `DB::raw` method also.

```
$products = Product::where('is_archive',0)->select(
            DB::raw('products.*'),
            DB::raw('(CASE WHEN pick_8 = 1 THEN "True" ELSE "False" END) AS pick_8'),
            DB::raw('(CASE WHEN pick_12 = 1 THEN "True" ELSE "False" END) AS pick_12'))->get()->toArray();
```

CASE statement will overwrite original values of pick_8 and pick_12 columns.

P.S. By the way. I guess you trying to use wrong tools to reach your goal. Take a look at [eloquent-mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: is there an option through which i dont apply the mutator to every operation, but to only specific requests? same question for accessors

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I don't see any mutators neither accessors in your question or my answer.

Comment: yes but you said i should take a look at eloquent mutators, so what i have learned so far is that when you apply a mutator it applies to every eloquent request. so is there a way to use mutator for only specific requests?